# Problem with transformation of Boolean expressions

Tags: boolean-algebra

Having some problem with beginner boolean algebra. Somehow I can't figure out these two problems.

Show that LHS is equal to RHS:

1. $wx + w'y + xyz = wx + w'y.$
   Can't find a way to "remove" $xyz$.
2. $zy' + yx' + z'x = z'y + y'x + zx'.$
   Tried different theorems but can't go from LHS to RHS.

Would appreciate the help, been trying for 5 hours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways to "remove" the summands is to use the absorption law $A + AB = A.$ Sometimes you need to add more variables to a summand by using the complementation law $A = xA + x'A.$

In the first problem, to remove $xyz$ using previous summands we need to add $w$ variable to it (since both of them contain it). We have the following chain of equalities:
\begin{align}wx + w'y + xyz &= wx + w'y + wxyz + w'xyz \\ 
&= wx + (wx)(yz) + w'y + (w'y)(xz)\\
&= wx + w'y.
\end{align}

For the second, add all variables (using complementation), regroup the summands and remove variables (again using complementation):
\begin{align}
zy' + yx' + z'x &= zy'x + zy'x' + yx'z + yx'z' + z'xy + z'xy'\\
&= z(y'x) + z'(y'x) + y(zx') + y'(zx') + x(z'y) + x'(z'y)\\
&= y'x + zx' + z'y. 
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! Just gotta say that your way of explaining is really good!

Comment: @Eqstor: I'm glad to help, and welcome to MSE. If this answer solved your problem you can mark it as accepted.